# JPA EclipseLink @ElementCollection not updating properly

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Using EclipseLink 2.3.2 with static weaving (Maven plugin) against OracleXE.

I have the following Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LIST")
public class List {

    ...Id...

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "LIST_CONTENTS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LIST_ID"))
    @OrderColumn(name = "SEQ")
    @Column(name = "CONTENT", length = 4000)
    private java.util.List<String> contents;

}
```

and when I update the contents by doing the following:

```
// newContents is a String[]
em.getTransaction().begin();
List list = em.find(List.class,id);
list.setContents(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(newContents)));
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I get a duplicate key error - like it didn't delete the old data

```
> Error Code: 1 Call: INSERT INTO NIBR_LIST_CONTENTS (LIST_ID, CONTENT,
> SEQ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>         bind => [3 parameters bound] Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="INSERT INTO NIBR_LIST_CONTENTS (LIST_ID, CONTENT,
> SEQ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:102)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
>         ... 54 more Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):
> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
> Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (ANNEX.NIBR_LIST_CONTENTS_PK) violated
> 
> Error Code: 1 Call: INSERT INTO NIBR_LIST_CONTENTS (LIST_ID, CONTENT,
> SEQ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>         bind => [3 parameters bound] Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="INSERT INTO NIBR_LIST_CONTENTS (LIST_ID, CONTENT,
> SEQ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:236)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:216)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(StatementQueryMechanism.java:115)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectCollectionMapping.performDataModificationEvent(DirectCollectionMapping.java:2080)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:157)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3799)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1415)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:636)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1505)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:267)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1143)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
>         ... 56 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique
> constraint (ANNEX.NIBR_LIST_CONTENTS_PK) violated
> 
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
>         ... 81 more
```

I've no idea what's wrong in the setup - I am using flyway to execute the SQL/DDL that I've written by hand.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you use for the primary key in the collection table?  The constraint is saying the pk constraint is violated, so check that you have it set appropriately - ie that you are not just using LIST_ID as the pk, since two elements on the same list will use hte same LIST_ID.  Either do not set a pk for the table, or use something unique like SEQ and LIST_ID.  If that is not the case, try turning on parameter logging to see what is being used, by setting the "eclipselink.logging.parameters" property to true.

Comment: Yep - the pk is (list_id, seq) - thanks for the tip on logging.  When I debug it I can see the DirectCollectionMapping has 7 changes - 4 inserts and then 3 deletes (test case replaces 3 values with 4) - it then goes through the list of changes in order - doing the insert first.

Comment: Tried my test with H2 and let EclipseLink generate the schema. Looked at the resulting schema and EclipseLink creates the table without a primary key so that it can insert and then delete but the deletes matches on list_id and contents.  Which is hella wrong if I update the list with a shared value.

Comment: This was tested so it should work, but I don't have the tests handy to check if it covered this same usecase.  It is expected to though, so file a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?classification=RT if it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how EclipseLink processes the elements of the ElementCollection (order), you cannot have a primary key of the join columns and the order column.  EclipseLink does handle updates properly with SQL that may or may not include the sequence column, but the order is such that the same LIST_ID, SEQ combination can exist for the same time in the transaction.

Remove the primary key and it all works.